# Move woocommerce widget price filter's slider handle starting position

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to make the woocommcerce widget price filter more visible by having the handle of the slider on a different starting postion. Eg. From the beginning of the range bar 10% towards the right.

See example below.

woocommerce price slider handle comparison of positions

[image]

Could this be done with css / html?

You can have a closer look to the sourcecode on: https://www.tequilaysoledad.com/shop/

Answer (score 0):

You need to set initial value for that slide somehow. I can`t check if this will work or not but try to add this in your header:

```
jQuery(function ($){
    $("#min_price").attr("value","10");
})
```

Comment: It didn't work but you gave me a good hint. I will try to find the answer by testing some JQuery lines and come back to you. Thanks

Comment: The point is that u need to set the initial value of that slider, because currently its 0. So you can use jquery to do that.